# C Builder (C++) AnsiString Length method

Tags: c++, vcl

I am used to program in c#, but now i had to help my roommate with a c++ project.

This is the "not working code" :

```
void  HighlightKeyWords::Highlight(TRichEdit eMemo,TRichEdit RichEdit1)
{
           ifstream file("KeyWords.txt");
           AnsiString temp;
           int maxWordLength=0;
           if(file.is_open())
        {
            while(file>>temp)
            {       if(temp.Length()> maxWordLength)
                    {
                            maxWordLength=temp.Trim().Length();
                    }
                    keyWords.push_back(temp);

            }
            file.close();
       }
       else
       {
            ShowMessage("Unable to open file. ");
       }
       for(unsigned i=0;i<KeyWords.size();i++)
       {
            richEdit1->Text=KeyWords[i];
       }
        eMemo->Text=MaxWordLength;
}
```

I get a list of keywords from the file. In MaxWordLength i want to know to maximum length of a word ( words are separated by new line in the text file ). When I do the temp.Length, i get 695 ( the number of all characters in the file ). Why am I not getting the actual length of the word i am adding to the vector?

Thank you!

LE: I also did the MaxWordLength logic in the for below, the for where i put the items in the RichEdit.

Comment: Your style is killing me. Please use lowercase letters for the first letter of a variable. The syntax highlighter is picking them up as classes.

Comment: Also, AnsiString doesn't have a ````>>```` operator. Where is the code for that?

Comment: The code for >> is part of the ifstream File variable. Every line of the file is introduced in the temp variable.I will use the lowercase for variable, edit is coming soon

Comment: Sorry let me reword: The operator ````>>```` for ifstreams does not include an implementation for ````AnsiString```` (see here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), it must be overloaded. I assume this code compiles so a ````istream& operator>> (AnsiString& val);```` must be defined somewhere.

Comment: Pro tip: don't do `grep operator>> dstring.h`

Comment: @mascoj this function is declared in the ansistring header but I can't find any documentation of what its expected behaviour is. Perhaps it reads the whole file

Comment: Why are you passing TRichEdit by value

Comment: @M.M Huh, okay. Good find. I was going by the VCL documentation. Don't have the headers on hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use file.getline() instead of the >> operator, which won't produce the desired output in your case, but gives you the full file content as result. So AnsiString().Length() is not your problem. Just modify part of your code to get it working as intended:

```
char buffer[255];

if(file.is_open()){
    while(file.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer))){
        temp = AnsiString(buffer).Trim();
        if(temp.Length()> maxWordLength) maxWordLength=temp.Length();
        keyWords.push_back(temp);
    }
    file.close();
}
```